# I want to know how to make my BUTTON START my animation in ANDROID

Tags: android, animation, button, android-animation, onclicklistener

I have simple 4 drawings(called frame 1,2,3,4) and my animation xml(called animationf) file inside my drawable folder.

I have a button in my layout, and I wanna make it start my animation with one touch. My button is invisible, so when a person touches the smartphone screen, it will start my animation.

I believe that I have to use something with OnClickLestener into my MainActivity java file.

MainActivity.java:

```
package e.ferreira.explodestress;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:maxWidth="50000dp"
    android:maxHeight="50000dp"
    android:minWidth="1dp"
    android:minHeight="1dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/start_button"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

animationf.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame1"
        android:duration="125"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame2"
        android:duration="125"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame3"
        android:duration="125"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/frame4"
        android:duration="125"/>
</animation-list>
```

Comment: you are correct, you will need an OnClickListener. There are plenty of tutorials online on how to implement one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get hold of the button by assignin it to a variable:

```
Button yourButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
```

Then you add an onClick listener to the button:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // Code for displaying your frames
     }
 });
```

Comment: May you help me telling how to put my code in there?
I'm a beginner.

Comment: I can't mate, you need to work that part out yourself. I have no idea what kind of animation you want or what your trying to do. The best thing to do is get coding, when you get stuck do some  research and break the problem down, work out what  questions to ask and post them here. I've answered your initial question so could you please mark it as answered ?

Comment: I did it. Thank you for your time.